# SCSS Import Relative to Root

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass, angular-cli

I'm in the process refactoring an Angular application and as I'm moving components around to new directory locations, I'm finding that dealing `@import` paths in the components' SCSS files is getting a bit tedious.

For example, let's say I have the file `src/_mixins.scss` in the root of my application and the component `src/app/my-widget/my-widget.component.scss` imports the SCSS like so `@import '../../mixins';`. All well and good.

But then I decide that `my-widget.component` is really be a "shared component" under another component `my-thingy.component`, so I create a `shared` folder under `src/app/my-thingy` and move everything that was in `src/app/my-widget` into it.

I *hope* you're still with me... So, now I've got `src/app/my-thingy/shared/my-widget` and I modify my SCSS file to import `@import '../../../../mixins'`.

**Note:** This is a simplified example. Some of the paths get relatively deep (no pun intended... *or was it?*) and all of these `.` and `/` are a bit much.

**TL;DR**

It would be *super-handy* if from the start I could have just imported  `_mixins.scss` relative to the root in all of my components' SCSS files so I don't have to keep messing with the `@import` paths when refactoring. (e.g. Something along the lines of `@import '~/mixins'`). **Does something like this exist?**

What I've tried (and, sadly, has failed):

1. `@import '~/mixins'; /** I had real hope for this one **/`
2. `@import 'mixins'; /** Just being overly optimistic here **/`
3. `@import '~//mixins'; /** Now I'm just making stuff up **/`

*I understand that I'm already going to have to modify my mod files to point to the new path of the component with all of this "moving stuff around", but...  hey, one less thing, right?*

Answer (score 80, accepted):

- If you are using Angular CLI, take a look at [Global styles](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-and-scripts-configuration), `"stylePreprocessorOptions"` option specifically.
- For webpack, you can configure `includePaths` in sassLoader plugin configuration.
- And it's similar for gulp builds, you pass `includePaths` to the sass plugin.

Whatever your build tool is, sass will treat those paths as root, so you can import them directly, so with:

```
includePaths: ["anywhere/on/my/disk"]
```

you can just `@import 'styles'` instead of `@import 'anywhere/on/my/disk/styles'`.

Comment: I had a problem with `npm test` (using Karma) after upgrading Angular 5 to Angular 7 using the automated CLI command. Turns out the "test.options" section in `angular.json` needed the `stylePreprocessorOptions` as well!

Comment: Thanks Boris, I had exactly the same problem!

Comment: Can't figure it out: let's say I use `@import "@import "~mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css` for my Angular library and it points to the 3rd party MapBox library CSS installed in `node_modules/mapbox-gl/...` - how to make it point to right direction in the app I install my library to, instead of `https://localhost:4200/~/mapbox-gl/...`?

Answer (score 19):

If I've understood the question correctly then using `@import 'src/app/...'` works correctly.

e.g.

```
@import 'src/mixins';
```

Note that there's no leading backslash on the path.

(this is tested on Angular 9)

Comment: Apparently, it no longer work in Angular 16, alas.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `{}` to reference the top level of the project path when using [meteor-scss](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-scss), hence something like that will work.

```
@import "{}/node_modules/module-name/stylesheet";
```

You can also use the tilda operator `~` If using `webpack` (or `angular-cli`), accessing libraries under `node_modules` as per the following -- *Credit to [@splintor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46635/splintor)*

```
@import "~module-name/stylesheet";
```

Comment: If using webpack (or angular-cli), accessing libraries under `node_modules` can also be done using the tilde operator - `@import "~module-name/stylesheet";`

Comment: @Jessycormier as explained in the answer `{}` represents the project root. Hence it may be easier to reference files from root (absolute reference) than a relative reference from file location (ex. via `../../`)

Comment: Neither Angular's webpack configuration nor the Jetbrains sass tools know how to resolve anything with this syntax.

Comment: Above referencing uses [meteor-scss](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-scss)

Answer (score 7):

The definition of paths depends on your version of Angular. In our project, old versions use `angular-cli.json` and new ones use `angular.json`:

for "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4" use angular-cli.json:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
      "../src",
      "./scss"
    ]
  },
```

for "@angular/cli": "~7.0.6":

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
       "./src",
       "./src/scss"
    ]
 }
```

Comment: And may I add that if you use preprocessor paths then you should not use tilde in import. I learn this in hard way.

Answer (score 4):

solution for angular-cli is to add `stylePreprocessorOptions` to `.angular-cli.json`.

```
{
    "apps": [{
        ...
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
            "includePaths": [
                "./app/global-styles"
            ]
        },
        ...
    }]
}
```

if you use server-side rendering remember to add this for both `ssr` and main app build -  otherwise you will get `NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\...\ClientApp\dist-server\main.bundle.js'`

```
{
    "apps": [{
            ...
            "outDir": "dist",
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                "includePaths": [
                    "./app/global-styles"
                ]
            },
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
            "name": "ssr",
            "outDir": "dist-server",
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                "includePaths": [
                    "./app/global-styles"
                ]
            },
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was

```
/* file src/assets/scss/app.scss */

@import "src/assets/css/style";
```

1. Removed the '.css' at the end of the file name,
2. Imported from "src/assets/...” (no backslash)

This imported a .css file from .scss in Angular 11 + Webpack,