# How to use global scss files in angular-cli project

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I am new to Angular 4 and to the Angular-CLI.
I cannot find any solution how to use root scss/css files for the whole application.
Thereby, my question, how to use global scss files in the project?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42865933/1876949

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a `styles` folder in the `src` folder, then you can import everything there into `styles.scss` which is also in the `src` folder. This is how mine looks:

```
// Vendors
@import './styles/vendors/_exports';

// Utils
@import './styles/utils/_exports';

// Globals
@import './styles/globals/_exports';

// Partials
@import './styles/partials/_exports';

// Components
@import './styles/components/_exports';
```

Every `_exports` file is importing all the files in the particular folder to make it easier to import it into the `styles.scss` file.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the comments, make sure that `styles.scss` is added to `styles` in the `angular-cli.json`file or it will not work.

Comment: Thank You :-) @Chrillewoodz

Comment: @EdgarQuintero Don't downvote just because you're doing it wrong. Have you added the styles.scss file to `styles` array of the angular cli json file? And made sure your project uses SCSS instead of CSS?

Comment: Sry, I had to modify the .angular-cli.json to include the folder src/styles/ folder, and it began to work correctly. "styles": ["styles.scss", "styles/variables.scss"],

Comment: @EdgarQuintero Glad to hear it works now. Mind removing the downvote?

Comment: Sure, I would suggest updating your answer with that detail though. :)

Comment: Well that file is added by default when creating a new CLI project, and any global styles have to be added to the `styles` array which should also be known. That's why I thought it was obvious. But I will add it.

Comment: styles.scss is added automatically, what isn't added are the new ones you are creating inside the /styles/ folders <----

Comment: @EdgarQuintero Those do not have to be added since you're importing them into `styles.scss`.

Comment: Great answer! Am I right if I have new style, then I should import it into main ‘.scss’ file? If yes, please, see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211121/imported-styles-are-not-applied-to-components/53211291?noredirect=1#comment93311168_53211291

Answer (score 9):

You will need to add the following code to you angular-cli.json **(angular.json on A6+)**

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
      "../src/assets/scss/base"
    ]
  },
```

Where `base` is the folder containing the file/s you want to `@import`.

Then you can just

```
// BEFORE
@import '../../100TIMES/variables';
// NOW
@import 'variables'; // src/assets/scss/base/_variables.scss
```

Thanks.

Note: YOU NEED TO REBUILD THE PROJECT TO RELOAD angular-cli.json **(angular.json on A6+)**

Answer (score 2):

There is also the option to add your css/scss file to the "styles" array in the .angular-cli.json file. There may be a "best practice" that gets broken by doing this - I'm not really sure of the rules. But if you include a file in that array, it will be injected as though it were loaded at the top of index.html.

Here is an example from one of my projects: (/.angular-cli.json)
    ...
    "styles": [
      "styles.scss",
      "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
      "../node_modules/mdi/scss/materialdesignicons.scss"
    ], 
    ...

Comment: Note that I had `style.css` in my `src` folder (not `.scss`) and if I included SCSS files inside that `style.css` file it would not error out but would not compile as SCSS. Once I updated `/.angular-cli.json` to use `style.scss` it compiled them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to load scss file in the very root component , in this way all the children components will get the styles.

And if there are many files , we can import those scss files into the one scss file by using `@import "scss-file";`

And if children component doesn't want to use that style , then we can also handle that via `encapsulation` property of `component`

Another way is to :

[stackoverflow.com/a/42865933/1876949](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865697/scss-import-relative-to-root/42865933#42865933)