# Imported Styles are not applied to components

Tags: css, angular, sass

I would like to create separate file to store styles for IE 9-11. To do it, I've created and imported file `InternetExplorer.scss` into 
main file `styles.scss`:

```
@import "scss/InternetExplorer.scss";
```

The `InternetExplorer.scss` has one style:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    .nav-tabs .nav-item {
        margin-bottom: -1px;
        z-index: 0;
    }
}
```

However, the declared styles  is not applied at the page.

However IE styles are applied perfectly, if I declare this style in styles property of component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tabComponent',    
    templateUrl: 'tabComponent.module.html',
    styles:
        `@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
            .nav-tabs .nav-item {
                margin-bottom: -1px;
                z-index: 0;
            }
         }`,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

Location of styles is:

```
app/styles.scss
app/scss/InternetExplorer.scss
```

Location of `tabComponent` is:

```
app/coreComponents/tabComponent
```

If I write with two dots `@import "../scss/InternetExplorer.scss";`,  then `File to import not found or unreadable: ../scss/InternetExplorer.scss.`

If I write with one dot `@import "./scss/InternetExplorer.scss";`,  then style is not applied.

The Angular version is 6.

How to apply styles from `InternetExplorer.scss`?

Comment: what is the path of your `scss` folder ?

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID I've added a path to the question.

Comment: I updated the answer , check it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Angular documentation :

> /* The AOT compiler needs the `./` to show that this is local */

Since your scss folder is not in the local , try to add `./` to the path :

```
@import "./scss/InternetExplorer.scss";
```

Comment: If I write `@import "../scss/InternetExplorer.scss";`,  then `File to import not found or unreadable: ../scss/InternetExplorer.scss.`
If I write with one dot `@import "./scss/InternetExplorer.scss";`,  then style is not applied.

Comment: can you please specify the path of the component ?

Comment: I've added path to the component to a question. Location of `tabComponent` is `app/coreComponents/tabComponent`

Comment: Thanks, it works. It was necessary to run again `npm-start`. Thank you very much!