# Import global LESS file in Angular's component

Tags: angular, angular9

On an Angular 9 home.component.less file I tried to import a global less file:

```
@import (reference) './mixins.less';
```

The file is on the project root along with index.html. So the structure is:

```
src
  mixins.less
  index.html
  app
    home
      home.component.less
```

When I build it I get the error:

```
Can't resolve './mixins.less' in '/project/src/app/home'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a path error.

Try

```
@import (reference) '../../mixins.less';
```

To search for the file in the src folder.

Comment: Yes, that works but I would like to not use a relative path. I would prefer something like: `@import (reference) '~mixins.less';` But I get the error with this.

Comment: You did not specify that in your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865697/scss-import-relative-to-root