# How to load an background image in the assets folder in scss, using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, sass, inspector

I'm trying to do this on angular, on styles.scss

```
.main-content {
    height: 80vh;
    padding: 30px;
    background-image: '/assets/adult-g3180e6c1c_1920.jpg';
}
```

But Google Inspector says this:
[Google Inspector comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnNzQ.png)

Help please!!!

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865697/scss-import-relative-to-root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```css
.main-content {
  height: 80vh;
  padding: 30px;
  background-image: url('assets/adult-g3180e6c1c_1920.jpg'); 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Problem Solved!!!